# On my ASP.NET site: Input[type='file'] looks 'old' in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11, input-type-file

On my ASP.NET site, `<input type="file">` renders like this in IE11 (an oldschool look):

[image: Oldschool IE11 look]

However, I want it to look like this (more modern look):

[image: More modern IE11 look]

When trying `<input type="file">` in the same IE11 elsewhere, in e.g. JSFiddle, it looks like I want it to (the more modern look).

I tried tracing CSS styles using F12 dev tools, but I cannot see any styles resulting in the oldschool look.
I'm using `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

My question: **What might be causing the oldschool look?**

Comment: Total guess: do you have compatibility mode set?

Answer (score 0):

IE11 Renders  that way.

If you want to change it you should use CSS, but it usually isn't easy.

What I usually do is to create my own fake component, with an input type text and a button styled the way I want.

I also have a input type file hidden, when I push my styled button I send via javascript a click to hidden input type file. When the file is selected I update my styled input type text with selected file name.

Comment: The odd part is that both images are renderings of the same `<input type="file">` tag in the same IE11 instance... The "only" difference is the context.

Comment: Probably JSFiddle adds some CSS layer that gives the different appaerance. Trust only what your browser shows on a plain html file.

Comment: It renders as desired (the modern look) when trying a completely plain html-file with these contents: `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body><input type="file"></body></html>`

Comment: Then something is modifying the style on your page, start stripping css files from your output.